# Why were interceptors planted on the police officers in Ghost in the Shell?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

Why were interceptors planted on the police officers in Ghost in the Shell?

I mean it was done by the government, but I don't know what was the motivation was for it.

The next episode seems to show that there was to be a laughing man patsy, but it's not clear what the interceptors are for.